# PC not recognizing Arduino when working with a class and MIDIUSB library

Tags: usb, arduino-due, midi

I've recently bought an Arduo Due to create some sort of a Midi controller together with the MIDIUSB library.

I have create a simple a test program with 1 potentiometer (without the use of a class) to test the MIDIUSB library and everything works fine, so I decided to expanded my program to make it work with more than 1 potentiometer (with the use of a class).

However my pc stopped recognizing my Arduino as a MIDI device with my updated code. When I upload my previous example code it all works fine. I get no compile errors or whatsoever.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
If anybody could explain me what I'm doing wrong or could give me a solution you would be a hero since I can't really work further if this issue doesn't get resolved.
Thanks!

Here is my code for Custom_MIDI_controller_V2.ino:

```
#include "MIDIUSB.h"
#include "Class.h"
#define TOLERANCE 8

byte NUMBER_POTS = 5;

Pot PO0(A0, 1, 14);
Pot PO1(A1, 1, 15);
Pot PO2(A2, 1, 16);
Pot PO3(A3, 1, 17);
Pot PO4(A4, 1, 18);

Pot *POTS[] = {&PO0, &PO1, &PO2, &PO3, &PO4};

void setup() {

}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_POTS; i++) {
    int potValue = POTS[i]->getValue();
      if(potValue != 255) {
        controlChange(POTS[i]->_channel, POTS[i]->_control, potValue);
        MidiUSB.flush();
      }
   }
}

void controlChange(byte channel, byte control, byte value) {
  midiEventPacket_t event = {0x0B, 0xB0 | channel, control, value};
  MidiUSB.sendMIDI(event);
}
```

Here is my Class.cpp code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Class.h"

#define TOLERANCE 8

Pot::Pot(int pin, int channel, int control) {
  _pin = pin;
  _channel = channel;
  _control = control;
  _value = analogRead(_pin);
  _oldValue = _value - 10;
}

int Pot::getValue() {
  int diff = abs(_value - _oldValue);
  if(diff > TOLERANCE)
  {
    _oldValue = _value;
    return map(_value, 0, 1023, 127, 0);
  } else {
    return 255;
  }
}
```

And this is my header Class.h code:

```
#ifndef Class_h
#define Class_h
#include "Arduino.h"

class Pot
{
  public:
    Pot(int pin, int channel, int control);
    int getValue();
    int _pin;
    int _channel;
    int _control;
    int _value;
    int _oldValue;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Unrelated error: `analogRead()` is called only once, in the constructor.

Comment: Please show the test program that worked.

Comment: @CL unrelated? That may well be the root cause - the constructor get called before `main()` which is where things like analogRead()` may be pre-configured. So it may never get past that point of the program.

Comment: What is the point of creating an array of pointers? Just create an array of objects as shown [here](https://tttapa.github.io/Control-Surface-doc/Doxygen/d3/d8d/Multiple-Control-Change-Potentiometers_8ino-example.html), for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care with constructors in C++.  They get called during the global variable initialisation phase of the execution, which happens before `main()` gets called.

`main()` calls the routines that initialise and configure the peripherals and such in the chip, and by having `analogRead()` in your constructor (which is itself another error I will mention below) there is a good chance (I don't know the full initialisation sequence of that chip though) that it will never complete, and thus your program hangs at that point.

Your `analogRead()` doesn't want to be in the constructor, anyway, since that will only execute once when the object is constructed.  Instead you want to have `analogRead()` called at the point you need to get the analog value. In your code that would be at the start of `int Pot::getValue()`.